# Basic OpenGLEs program Issue

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am learning OpenGlEs for android. I am trying to execute a very basic program of Clearing Screen.But i am failing to execute.
Below is my program.

**MainActivity**

```
   package com.learning.opengl;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.pm.ConfigurationInfo;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView;
    private boolean rendererSet = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        glSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);

        final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final ConfigurationInfo configurationInfo = activityManager.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
        final boolean supportGlEs2 = configurationInfo.reqGlEsVersion >= 0x2000;

        if(supportGlEs2){
            glSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
            //glSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
            glSurfaceView.setRenderer(new CustomRenderer());
            rendererSet = true;
            Toast.makeText(this,"The Version is :"+(configurationInfo.reqGlEsVersion >= 0x2000),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
         else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"This device does not support OpenGL ES 2.0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        if(rendererSet)
        {
            glSurfaceView.onResume();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();

        if(rendererSet)
        {
            glSurfaceView.onPause();
        }
    }
}
```

**CustomRenderer**

```
package com.learning.opengl;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glClear;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glClearColor;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glViewport;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;

public class CustomRenderer  implements Renderer{

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {

    }   glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

I did n't any any permissions in Android manifest file. When i am executing this program on real device Motox

I got the Following error

```
05-24 14:49:21.396: E/Adreno-ES20(10379): <gl_external_unsized_fmt_to_sized:2379>: QCOM> format, datatype mismatch
05-24 14:49:21.396: E/Adreno-ES20(10379): <get_texture_formats:3009>: QCOM> Invalid format!
```

I googled it . but no luck.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the test you're using with `reqGlEsVersion` from `ConfigurationInfo` does what you intended. It gives the value of the version you requested in the manifest. If you didn't specify ES 2.0 in the manifest, the test will fail.

If you plan to support ES 2.0 only, make sure that you have this in your manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
```

If you really do intend to support multiple OpenGL versions, you need a different runtime test. The section "Checking OpenGL ES Version" on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html explains how to do that. In summary, you have two options:

- You create an OpenGL context with the minimum version you plan to support, and query for the actual context version after you created it. I'm not convinced this will work reliably because some devices don't for example support ES 1.0 and ES 2.0+ with the same context.
- You try to create a context with the highest version you want to use, and check for failure of the context creation.